# bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente error al cargar la libreria **bootstrap.bundle.min.js**

Este me muestra el siguiente mensaje en la consola del navegador. (Estoy usando chrome)

***DevTools no ha podido cargar el mapa de la fuente: No se ha podido analizar el contenido de http:// localhost/X/Assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0***

Alguna recomendación sobre como solucionar dicho problema.

Comment: Si no vemos el código es dificil ayudar, y mira que nos gusta, pero necesitamos que pongas de tu parte tambien. Ya te comenté en una de tus otras preguntas que debes ponernos [example] pero aún no lo has hecho en ninguna. En este caso, a ciegas, lo unico que se me ocurre es que tengas un espacio entre http:// y localhost por lo que muestra el error. Más no se decirte así, lo siento. `http:// localhost/X/Assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map`

Comment: No es que no quiera publicar el codigo, simplemente no se ni donde ni cuando ocurrio ese error. He estado buscando e investigando pero no encuenntro nada. Y gracias por responder.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.